# unable to install ibm_db gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, db2

I am getting below error on installing ibm_db gem. Got no idea what is causing this. I am using ruby on Win 7 32-bit and i am using ibm_data_server_driver_package_win32_v10.5 downloaded from IBM website.

```
D:\Users\zzuj001>gem install ibm_db -- '--with-IBM_DB-include="C:\Program Files\
IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include" --with-IBM_DB-lib="C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM
DATA SERVER DRIVER\lib"'
ERROR:  Error installing ibm_db:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-IBM_DB-include="C:\Program Files\I
BM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include" --with-IBM_DB-lib="C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM D
ATA SERVER DRIVER\lib"
Detected 32-bit Ruby

Detected usage of IBM Data Server Driver package. Ensure you have downloaded 32-
bit package of IBM_Data_Server_Driver and retry the 'gem install ibm_db' command


creating gil_release_version
creating unicode_support_version
checking for SQLConnect() in -ldb2cli... yes
checking for gil_release_version... yes
checking for unicode_support_version... yes
creating Makefile
extconf.rb:114:in `libpathflag': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated
 Config.
extconf.rb:114:in `libpathflag': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated
 Config.

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating ibm_db-i386-mingw32.def
compiling ibm_db.c
In file included from C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlcli
.h:983:0,
                 from C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlcli
1.h:45,
                 from ruby_ibm_db_cli.h:52,
                 from ibm_db.c:27:
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1747:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1750:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1753:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1864:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1867:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1870:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1890:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1893:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1896:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1899:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1906:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1908:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1910:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1912:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1919:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1921:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1926:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1929:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1932:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1935:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1938:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1941:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1951:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1953:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1960:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1970:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1973:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1976:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1982:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1985:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1988:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1991:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:1997:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2000:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2003:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2017:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2020:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2023:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2030:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2033:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2035:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_ecount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2038:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2086:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2127:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2128:5: error: unkn
own type name '__out_bcount_opt'
C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\include/sqlext.h:2129:5: error: unkn
own type name '__in'
ibm_db.c:93:0: warning: "STRCASECMP" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ibm_db.c:21:
c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1645:0: note: this is the location of
the previous definition
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_free_conn_struct':
ibm_db.c:475:7: warning: variable 'rc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variab
le]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_free_stmt_handle_and_resources':
ibm_db.c:680:7: warning: variable 'rc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variab
le]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_check_sql_errors':
ibm_db.c:991:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_connect_helper':
ibm_db.c:2504:5: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ruby_ibm_db_createDb_helper':
ibm_db.c:2922:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ruby_ibm_db_dropDb_helper':
ibm_db.c:3051:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_createDBNX':
ibm_db.c:3198:9: warning: unused variable 'return_value' [-Wunused-variable]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_bind_param_helper':
ibm_db.c:3413:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c:3433:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c:3453:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c:3474:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_close':
ibm_db.c:3706:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c:3724:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_column_privileges':
ibm_db.c:3901:13: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_columns':
ibm_db.c:4081:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_foreign_keys':
ibm_db.c:4247:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_primary_keys':
ibm_db.c:4403:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_procedure_columns':
ibm_db.c:4594:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_procedures':
ibm_db.c:4751:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_special_columns':
ibm_db.c:4928:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_statistics':
ibm_db.c:5123:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_table_privileges':
ibm_db.c:5282:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_tables':
ibm_db.c:5456:11: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_commit':
ibm_db.c:5538:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_do_prepare':
ibm_db.c:5618:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_exec':
ibm_db.c:5756:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_free_result':
ibm_db.c:5831:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_execute':
ibm_db.c:6936:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c:7024:73: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expres
sions [-Wsign-compare]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_next_result':
ibm_db.c:7721:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_num_fields':
ibm_db.c:7820:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_num_rows':
ibm_db.c:7913:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function '_ruby_ibm_db_get_column_by_name':
ibm_db.c:7969:9: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_field_display_size':
ibm_db.c:8132:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_field_type':
ibm_db.c:8326:30: warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointe
r target type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8349:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8357:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8360:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8363:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8366:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8369:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8372:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8375:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c:8378:15: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer ta
rget type [enabled by default]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_field_width':
ibm_db.c:8452:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_rollback':
ibm_db.c:8558:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_result':
ibm_db.c:9147:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_fetch_row':
ibm_db.c:9950:5: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared at
 c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_result_cols':
ibm_db.c:9989:9: warning: unused variable 'ret_val' [-Wunused-variable]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_fetch_assoc':
ibm_db.c:10118:5: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_fetch_object':
ibm_db.c:10205:5: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_fetch_array':
ibm_db.c:10287:5: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_fetch_both':
ibm_db.c:10363:5: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_server_info':
ibm_db.c:11114:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: In function 'ibm_db_client_info':
ibm_db.c:11401:7: warning: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' is deprecated (declared a
t c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:839) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
ibm_db.c: At top level:
ibm_db.c:42:13: warning: '_ruby_ibm_db_set_decfloat_rounding_mode_client' declar
ed 'static' but never defined [-Wunused-function]
ibm_db.c:43:14: warning: '_ruby_ibm_db_instance_name' defined but not used [-Wun
used-variable]
ibm_db.c:2539:12: warning: '_ruby_ibm_db_set_decfloat_rounding_mode_client_helpe
r' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
make: *** [ibm_db.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ibm_db-2.
5.17 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.0.0/ib
m_db-2.5.17/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

ibm_db should be available in binary form on Windows, so you wouldn't need to compile it yourself. You may need to explicitly specify the platform.

```
$ gem search -r ibm_db

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

ibm_db (2.5.17 ruby universal-darwin-13 x86-mingw32 x86_64-linux, 2.5.14 x86-linux, 2.5.11 x86-mswin32-60, 2.5.5 mswin32)
```

You probably want the x86-mingw32 binary.

I think the following command will install it:

```
gem install ibm_db --platform x86-mingw32
```

This should not require compilation.

(I can't verify as I'm not currently on Windows.)

Comment: getting the same error with "gem install ibm_db --platform x86-mingw32"

Answer (score 0):

I working with IBM_DB but version 9.7 on windows

Yo can do the next steps (working with rails 3):

Go to gems page and download the ibm_db gem for mingw32 for example the version 2.5.7, then install from file downloaded directy for example:

```
gem install c:\folder_downloads\ibm_db-2.5.7-x86-mingw32.gem
```

Additionally you can append --force if you desired but, doing that, it can maybe install additional unnecessary gems than can uninstall without problems

If you want to compile gem on windows depend of gem version and each version have a instruction in his documentation for set environments variables (windows paths) before compiling and, of course, you should  have a configured devkit for compiling native gems, and for last, have a correct installation of db2 client or server.